# UITabViewControllers - Load Second View first based on some conditions

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Beginner here.

I'm trying to make an iOS app using the Tab View Controllers, and I kinda ran into a problem , at least I don't know how to do it .

The Tabs Look like this : First Choice, Second Choice, Settings ( here I'll have some text fields and a save button , and everything will be saved in a plist. ) .
Basically what I'm trying to do is , the first time the App is lunched, i want to make an if statement to check if the plist file exists and the data is there. IF Yes , just load normally with the First Choice View Controller , if NOT , Load Settings View Controller .

Any ideas on how to do this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a relatively contrived example because no sample code was provided but it should work.

In your `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or you could do `willEnterForeground`, run your plist check.

Then depending on the success or failure set the `selectedIndex` which is a property of `UITabBarController` to whichever one you'd like.